# Set different types for a dict key in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have the following code in TypeScript:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  auth: {user: null},
  setAuth: (auth: any) => {}
})

export const AuthContextProvider = (props: any) => {

  const setAuth= (auth: any) => {
    setState({...state, auth: auth})
  }

  const initState = {
    auth: {user: null},
    setAuth: setAuth
  } 

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState)

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

It works fine until I try to initialize `initState = {auth: {user: "username", setAuth: setAuth}}` because I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ auth: { user: string; }; setAuth: (auth: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ auth: { user: null; }; setAuth: (auth: any) => void; }'.
  The types of 'auth.user' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
    20 |
    21 |   return (
  > 22 |     <AuthContext.Provider value={state}>
       |                           ^^^^^
    23 |       {props.children}
    24 |     </AuthContext.Provider>
    25 |   )
```

How can I indicate `auth.user` to be null or string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` operator when you are creating the context to indicate that `user` can be `null` or `string`.

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  auth: { user: null as null | string },
  setAuth: (auth: any) => {}
})
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAERSoYsDcAUD0gA9IsOGggA7QvACC%20GAAsAwhMoD4AXkQcYAOjTsKSZeNUwAFDh5w4KOfIBcuAsSiPx%20ADYebhOO69wAD5wUlDA4gDmNJhWIUgwsgqOZrZJNuIAngCUcOoAfLjUPNRZfILC8GKSMnbGpgAKjABuwAAmSFC5cGZgjGCEjiiZOfm4fNZVUnEJdpopdoPDuQWW1tbEMGSGFjq7UobYqQ42diWxRbGT8OHAm%20SUXatrR444RB2OLCgARmgs0bF1vFEscNiDznBxqIJFMANr7SjYDZbSgAXS67xRSDMNzuhlKsXYMHwUHE3UBcAAPCC6oJdI0IC12p0migPPgkOocAikNQ8hTrDhehB%20np5MAPK12OIimsqQB6GkqOk6BlMjr86ylahAA)